# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/dropwizard/jetty/RequestLogFactory when using dropwizard

Tags: java, hibernate, jetty, dropwizard

When I changed from Hibernate to JDBI, and tried to launch my application, error below occured

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/dropwizard/jetty/RequestLogFactory

Stack trace says, that the cause of this problem is in my configuration class, at the class definition. But i have no idea what's wrong. Anyone had this problem?

**MyConfiguration.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @JsonProperty
    @NotNull
    private DataSourceFactory database;

    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String someString;


    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }

    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }
}
```

EDIT
I'm using dropwizard 1.0.0 and RequestLogFactory is neither in the given package nor Intellij couldn't find that class.

Comment: The `RequestLogFactory` is in [a new artifact and package](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-request-logging) with 1.0.0. `dropwizard-core` [should pull it in](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-core/pom.xml#L85). I would make sure all your dependencies are actually updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the RequestLogFactory directly, but it seems one of the classes you're importing is and that jar needs to be present on your classpath for these classes you're importing to work appropriately at runtime. You should track down the jar which you need to include on your classpath that includes the RequestLogFactory class.

Comment: This class is not existing in my current dropwizard version

Comment: Right, i'm saying this package might be in another "dropwizard" jar that needs to be put on your classpath. I found the project [1] I would expect to find this RequestLogFactory class in, but I don't see it. I did find the RequestLogFactory in another project though [2].

[1] https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty

[2] https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-request-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/request/logging/RequestLogFactory.java

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be you're missing an import statement for the RequestLogFactory class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

You probably need to include:

```
import io.dropwizard.jetty.RequestLogFactory;
```

or simply (if you have more classes inside of jetty):

```
import io.dropwizard.jetty.*;
```

Comment: I've edited my question. RequestLogFactory is there no longer